# Amazon RDS MySQL limitations

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have a web app that's quite data-heavy. The application is currently storing approximately 5k rows (logs) a day into a MySQL RDS micro instance (all settings default - InnoDB, UTF8,etc). Each log is pretty small.. only 4 columns (int, int, timestamp, varchar(20)). I didn't run to any problems yet, but I'm afraid what will happen in a couple of months.

Therefore I would like to ask what are the limitations of a table in such a database. Are there any row limits? My data store limit is 5GB, but with such lean data I don't think that will be a problem. I think that some database limits will be a much bigger problem here.

Additional info: The data stored daily will most likely grow in time.

Thank you and sorry for my database managing newbie-ness :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no row limit in a InnoDB table http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html , there's (huge) table size limit but you'll run into other constrains before hitting it.

I suggest just in case to plan for an archiving strategy, where you move to another table/database old data.

Comment: What do you mean by other constrains? It happened to me once when I was locally running MySQL that I couldn't insert new rows after reaching approximatelly 70k rows in a table. Table size wasn't even 5 MB. This is the reason of my question..

Comment: As per the link, there's no limit on the number of rows in a InnoDB table (mysql doesn't even keep a count on it) and thoretical maximum table size is 64TB so you are hitting some other limit or constrain first (likely the server itself), like file size of 2GB in older operating systems etc. You'll have to investigate logs etc to see what's exactly the problem when you can't add more rows.